# Javascript instantiation in a closure. How to make Factory and Model independent?

Tags: javascript, closures

**This is a browser.** Js-code sample is really simple.

**Case 1:**

```js
var settingsImportantPrefix = {
     primitiveProperty: 1
};

var Model = function() {
     var self = this;
     self.getA = function() {
          return settings.primitiveProperty;
     }
};

var factory = function(settings) {
     return (function(settings) {
          return new Model();
     }(settings));
}

var test = factory(settingsImportantPrefix );
test.getA();
```

And it doesn't work for me. Closure settings in this example are NOT visible in the new instance of the model returned!

But on the other hand.

**Case 2:**

```js
var settingsImportantPrefix = {
  primitiveProperty: 1
};

var factory = function(settings) {
  return (function(settings) {
    var Model = function() {
      var self = this;
      self.getA = function() {
        return settings.primitiveProperty;
      }
    };
    return new Model();
  }(settings));
};

var test = factory(settingsImportantPrefix);
test.getA() //1
```

Works as it is supoosed to. Settings are visible inside of the new instance.

***It seems to me a bit strange that a closure doesn't create its own scope to store values. Is it a "closure definition" requirement to keep Model function  body inside of closure body?***

***Is there way to make Model and Factory independent?***

My aim is to separate Factory and Model. I pass settings object (wrapped into Model) as a parameter, so I need to check if it is an instance of Model (that is why Model has to be independent).

P.S.: I don't like the idea to return Model in the following way Factory.Model.

Comment: Both code works fine for me in the browser (provided the file containing `Model()` is included first, otherwise it's undefined). It doesn't work as you expect in node.js (first example outputs undefined) because in node.js each file has its own context (wrapped in a closure)

Comment: Why a closure doesn't create its own scope to get the value?

Comment: Are you referring to node.js or the browser? In the case of the browser, if you are seeing what you see then it's because the file that contains `Model()` is included after the rest of the code have executed so when the code executes `Model` is undefined. If you are referring to node.js it's because every file is it's own separate closure and so variables in files are prevented from polluting the scope of other files.

Comment: I have clarified the Factory and Model usage. Now the task semms to be more clear.

Comment: Why can't `settings` be a property of the `Model`?

Comment: Factory produces Models based on settings objects (here in code sample there is only one settingsImportantPrefix object but there are many in practise). Otherwise I don't need factory too. :)

Comment: Ah. OK. I see it now. Sorry, I misunderstood/misread the question. Guffa's answer is correct: it's because `settings` is part of `factory's` closure and not part of `Model's` closure. I think you're misunderstanding what closures are. Closure and scope is almost the same thing. If one thing is out of scope, it's also out of closure. Scope is like Class and closures are like Objects. Closures are instances of scope.

Comment: I do not pass parameters into Model, I want to play with closures and pass model argument using closure.

Comment: Is there any way to separate Model and Factory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's different because there are different scopes. When you call a function it won't inherit the scope of the code that called it, it gets its scope when it is created.

This can be shown simpler; this won't work because the variable `a` is not in the scope where the function `show` is created:

```
function show() {
  console.log(a);
}

function caller() {
  var a = 1;
  show();
}
```

This works because the variable `a` is in the scope where function `show` is created:

```
function caller() {
  var a;

  function show() {
    consle.log(a);
  }

  a = 1;
  show();
}
```

This also works, as the variable `a` is in the scope where the function `show` is created, and it doesn't need to be in the scope where the function is called:

```
function creator() {
  var a = 1;

  function show() {
    console.log(a);
  }

  return show;
}

var showFunc = creator();
showFunc();
```

Comment: I have clarified the Factory and Model usage. Now the task semms to be more clear.

Comment: Is there any way to separate Model and Factory?

Comment: @spirit: Yes, but then you need to send everything that the constructor needs in the call.

Comment: Yep, I just thought recently about it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all - your examples' output is wrong in the first case - the first case generates `1` and not `undefined` as you wrote

But, there is a difference between the two though they have the same output.
The scope of variables used inside functions is determined when you **define** the function rather than when you **use** it.

In your first case - the settings object that is being used is the **global** `settings` variable, while in the second case - the `settings` variable that is used is the **local** variable. But still, because objects in JavaScript passed by reference - it is eventually using the same variable (changing the value of `settings.primitiveProperty` will change the output in both cases.

Comment: Both cases have input parameters. I have updated the code.

Comment: OK so both will generate 1 - your first case's output is not `undefined`